# Getting INSERT errors when I do UPDATE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, error-handling

At work we have a SQL Server database. I don't know the db that well. I have created a new column in the table for some new functionality....straight away I have started seeing errors

My statement was this:

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD locked varchar(50) NULL
GO
```

The error is:

> *Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition*

I have read that the error message appears when during an INSERT operation either the number of supplied column names or the number of supplied values does not match the table definition.

But I have checked so many times and i have changed the PHP code to include this columns data yet I still receive the error.

I have run the SQL query directly on the db and still get the error.

Funny enough the query which gets the error is an Update.

```
UPDATE "users"
SET "users"."date_last_login" = GETDATE()
WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: this is probably due to a trigger as @craigtaub says in the answer. Look for those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered it could be a trigger causing it?

This is the error message you would get.

If its an Update action causing it check trigger actions that Updates on that table run.

Do it with:

```
#sp_helptrigger Users, 'UPDATE';
```

This will show triggers occuring with ‘update’ actions.

If there is a trigger, grab the triggers name and run the below (but replace TriggerNameHere with real trigger):

```
#sp_helptext TriggerNameHere;
```

This will give you any SQL that the trigger runs and could be the INSERT the error message is referring to.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes I can see there is a trigger and it is doing an INSERT into a table. I should be able to fix it from here. Theres a column required in the statement which is missing. I'm annoyed it doesn't say query from trigger. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Aside from `TRIGGERS`,

the reason for that is because you are using `implicit` type of `INSERT` statement. Let's say your previous number of columns on the table is 3. You have this syntax of `INSERT` statement,

```
INSERT INTO tableName VALUES ('val1','val2','val3')
```

which executes normally fine. But then you have altered the table to add another column. All of your `INSERT` queries are inserting only three values on the table which doesn't matches to the total number of columns.

In order to fix the problem, you have to update all `INSERT` statements to insert 4 values on the table,

```
INSERT INTO tableName VALUES ('val1','val2','val3', 'val4')
```

and it will normally work fine.

I'll advise you to use the `EXPLICIT` type of `INSERT` wherein you have to specify the columns you want to insert values with. Eg,

```
INSERT INTO tableName (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('val1','val2','val3')
```

in this ways, even if you have altered your tables by adding additional columns, your `INSERT` statement won't be affected unless the column doesn't have a default value and which is non-nullable.

Comment: Hi, thanks, yes I saw very quickly that the SQL that the trigger runs was doing this so have fixed it, it just took me ages to find as I couldn't understand why an update would cause this.